# when i fire insert query i get Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

I am new to this forum and new to C# web programming. I am developing LMS (Library Management system) using SQL Server and Visual Studio ver 16. I have an issue with the insertion of data into the database. the same code I used in other pages and work perfectly. put hardcoded values in insert statement and it worked perfectly which means that there is no issue with connection to database so where is the issue? it can be the text boxes etc name and property which I also checked and found correct. code is as follows

```
try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();

        }
        // SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;// beow is the way to write a query like ist put '' then iside we have "" and then isde we  have ++ and then inside we have text box name
        // cmd.CommandText= "INSERT INTO member_master_tbl values('"++"','"++"','"++"','"++"','"++"','"++"','"++"','"++"','"++"')"
        // cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO member_master_tbl (full_name,dob,contact_no,email,state,city,pincode,full_address,member_id,password) values ('" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox2.Text.Trim() + "','"+TextBox4.Text.Trim()+"','" + TextBox3.Text.Trim() + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + TextBox6.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox7.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox5.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox8.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox9.Text.Trim() + "');";

        //notr thr col nsmes in the query are case sensitive
        String status = "pending";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member_master_tbl (full_name,dob,contact_no,email,state,city,pincode,full_address,member_id,password,account_status)values(@full_name,@dob,@contact_no,@email,@state,@city,@pincode,@full_address,@member_id,@password,@account_status);", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_no", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox6.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pincode", TextBox7.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_address", TextBox5.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member_id", TextBox8.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox9.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status",status);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Successful. Go to User Login to Login');</script>");
    }
    catch (SqlException  ex)
    {

        Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your question please add the full exception details for any exception message that occurs, not just the type. You can see the value with `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: When using parameters be sure that the parameter value is the same as the type in the database. Example: If the DateOfBirth (dob)  column has the schema type `Date` then the value for the parameter should be of type System.DateTime and not string. If the value is currently a string then you should parse it first using DateTime.Parse or ParseExact or TryParse and use the resulting value as the Parameter value.

Comment: you have to make to sure the types are correct... i see you are passing only strings with AddWithValue.... Also can you post the entire exception with the stacktrace?

Comment: Now the TextMode is Date, Email, SingleLine etc of the Textboxes and the dataType of all Columns in a table is of varchar(50) .

Comment: please elaborate how can I display the complete exception as u said

Comment: `please elaborate how can I display the complete exception as u said` ← I literally provided the code to do exactly that in the very first comment.

Comment: @ Jonathan, because all the Columns in table are of type String. Can u help me in my code how to use stacktrace please

Comment: any suggestion please

Comment: @Igor. I use the code u advised but nothing get popup

Comment: Replace `ex.Message` with `ex.ToString()`

Comment: If you are using C# and SQL Server, I would strongly recommend using Entity Framework.  Tools inside Visual Studio can can generate the models and DataContext for your existing database.  This is called "Database First."  Once you have done that, it will be simple to insert and update records.

Comment: issue resolved. I have managed to get the detailed error so then I took seconds to solve it. common error.

Comment: ex.ToString() didnt worked .